# Why is Promethium the only radioactive Lanthanide?

Tags: periodic-table, radioactivity

Why is it that only Promethium (Pm) is the only radioactive lanthanide?

I was trying to figure out what percentage of all radioactive elements in the Periodic Table the f-block accounts for, when it struck me that Promethium was the only radioactive lanthanide shown. I found this a bit odd, since I expected to see a couple of other radioactive elements there as well, especially since Promethium is (somewhat) near the middle of the series.

Comment: Nuclear properties have _absolutely_ nothing to do with chemistry (f-block and everything). Promethium being radioactive is just bad luck. Technetium is another such case.

Comment: Glen Seaborg might disagree a little bit on it being chemistry or not ;), but @IvanNeretin is generally correct. The issue isn't f-electrons so much as nuclear structure, where it turns out that the Samarium nucleus is more tightly bound (see nuclear shell model), so flipping one of Promethium's neutrons to a proton results in a lower-energy nucleus (not that it stops there in general, but...).

Comment: It is not the only radioactive lanthanide. It is the only one with no stable isotopes. Other stable lanthanides also have naturally occurring radioactive isotopes ([samarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_samarium) is a good example).

Comment: @IvanNeretin  I would advise against making such a sweeping absolutist statement.  It is well-established that nuclear properties *can* affect chemical properties.  Granted, it's not typical, but it's nevertheless incorrect to take the hard-line stance that it doesn't happen at all.  See, for instance:  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00222348808212315?src=recsys

Comment: @theorist See, in natural sciences there is always an exception, or a subtlety, or a tiny deviation in nearly any rule and law. If we start with exceptions, the students never get to know the rules in the first place. Here I stand, and I can do no other.

Comment: @IvanNeretin while I agree this one would be better in the physics forum there are number of things in chemistry that depend on nuclear properties. Can we no longer discuss NMR here? A few others that come to mind with a few seconds thought are the kinetic isotope effect, Mossbauer spectroscopy, isotope shifts in vibrational spectroscopy and neutron activation analysis

Answer (score 11):

Lanthanoids are not generally supposed to be radioactive, with exception of mentioned very [long lived radioisotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_radioactive_nuclides_by_half-life).

The longest half-life radioactive nuclides of lanthanoids ( in years )

> $\ce{^{150}Nd}:\ \pu{6.7e18}$
>   $\ce{^{151}Eu}:\  \pu{5e18}$
>   $\ce{^{148}Sm}:\  \pu{7e15}$
>   $\ce{^{144}Nd}:\   \pu{2.29e15}$
>   $\ce{^{152}Gd}:\  \pu{ 108e12}$
>   $\ce{^{147}Sm}:\ \pu{106e9}$
>   $\ce{^{138}La}:\ \pu{ 102e9}$
>   $\ce{^{176}Lu}:\ \pu{ 38.5e9}$

[Promethium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promethium) is rather a victim of [circumstances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promethium#Isotopes) there was no free position to have at least one stable isotope. It is related also to the [Liquid drop model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula).

There are few semi-empirical rules, related to proton and neutron fermionic pairing within the nucleus model:

Elements with the odd proton number have maximally 2 stable isotopes.

2 Isotopes of adjacent elements with the same nucleon number, like $\ce{^N_{A}X, ^N_{A+1}Y}$, are not both stable. ( But some of these unstable ones  have very long half-life as seen above.)

Isotopes not close enough to the [Valley of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_of_stability#Description) are not stable, as they have too little or too many neutrons.

The stability of isotopes of similar nucleon number generally decreases in order

- both [proton/neutron numbers are even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_nuclide#Physical_magic_numbers_and_odd_and_even_proton_and_neutron_count)
- one number is odd, the other is even.
- both numbers are odd.

For Pm and Tc, both have odd proton numbers what gives them disadvantage.

All their possible stable isotope candidates are already taken by their  neighbors as energetically preferred variants. Therefore all isotopes of given 2 elements beta decay to nuclei of adjacent elements with less energy.

Answer (score 1):

We may also seek odd neutron counts that fail to give stable nuclei, like 43 or 61 with protons. The first "unlucky" number with neutrons is only 19 (meaning there are stable nuclei with 1,3,5,...,17 neutrons but not 19). Trace amounts of sulfur-35 ($\ce{^_{16}^{35}S}$) do occur as a [cosmogenic nuclide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmogenic_nuclide), generated by cosmic-ray spallation of argon.

Comment: Additional fact: The heaviest stable "odd-odd" nucleus is nitrogen-14. For heavier ones is instability due odd-odd parity bigger factor than the deviation from the "valley of stability". (there are heavier ones, that are kinetically almost stable like Tantalum-180m)

Comment: @Poutnik potassium-40. Had this not been so kinetically stubborn potassium would be monoisotopic and 19, unlucky with neutrons, would be almost so with protons. We  nearly don't have liquid soap (often made with KOH).

Comment: But this is still quite radioactive, halflife comparable to uranium-238 or thorium-232.